# Angular equivalent of J Query

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble trying to find the angular equivalent, admittedly I'm in dire need of more angular experience. Using J-Query I was able to output accelerometer data to the app in a live feed so they constantly updated as the phone moved around. To explain, there would be 4 values on screen that are constantly changing. I was able to do so with the below code which would output the result into a div on some event.

```
function gotMotion(accelerometer) {
var acc = "";
    acc += "X Motion: " + accelerometer.x.toFixed(3) + " m/s" + "<br/>";
    acc += "Y Motion: " + accelerometer.y.toFixed(3) + " m/s" + "<br/>";
    acc += "Z Motion: " + accelerometer.z.toFixed(3) + " m/s" + "<br/>";
    acc += "Timestamp: " + accelerometer.timestamp;
    $("#targetDiv").html(acc);
}
```

I've tried methods such as `<div ng-controller = "mycontroller">`

Putting a function or value within the scope and then using `{{acc}}` or put in a function and try `{{acc()}}` to show but two things happen

1. Outputs the last values
2. Outputs every value recorded in a list

Any ideas ?

Comment: what did you want to do ?

Comment: Are you sure that your values are being changed within the digest cycle? Also are you using the correct scope? If you have values being changed outside of the digest cycle then angular is unaware and the digest cycle will not run.

Comment: What you describe should be very trivial with Angular. The problem is, you haven't shown us enough to help you debug why it's not working. We'll need to see your Angular module definitions and the HTML markup you're using. Armed with that I have absolutely no doubt that someone in the SO community will be able to help you get this working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with Angular you have to forget as much as you can the use of JQuery. don't use DOM manipulation with Jquery. IT is very bad practise because Angular will not notice change immediatly and there Angular Way to do it.

Secondly, I don't really know what you try or you want. 
this is an example of how to share a data between controller and a view with $scope.

This is a plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/umNjPs5a7mBCkx5mqzwR?p=preview

**CONTROLLER**

```
// Declare the main module
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope',  function($scope) {
     // if you to access a variable in the view put it $scope
     $scope.acc = [];
     for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
       $scope.acc.push("X Motion: "+i+" M/S");
     }


}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
       <!-- ng-repeat iterate over a list --> 
       <ul ng-repeat="a in acc">
          <li>{{a}}</li>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```